# PWM pin of microcontroller, what is it for?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

I always see PWM pin in microcontrollers, like in PIC what is/are the use of it?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_width_modulation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While PWM is indeed used for motor control, I'd say the main use for PWM is digital to analog conversion, in case the MCU doesn't have a DAC on chip (they most often don't). The PWM duty cycle can be used to represent an analog value, if you connect the PWM output to an op amplifier. This is a quite common design in all kinds of applications.

Most kinds of systems reglating something is using a PWM + an op amp to give an analog output, which can be used to control some sort of hardware. Then this analog output can be read back into the MCU, through an analog to digital converter, and the MCU can alter the PWM duty cycle accordingly.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the general DAC case.  I've also seen them logically ORed with an asynchronous serial data stream for FSK communications.

Answer (score 8):

It stands for Pulse Width Modulation.  It's a way to send a simulation of an analog signal using digital equipment, so you can simulate a voltage that's between your high and low voltage.

All I know how to do with it is light up LEDs off an Arduino :-)

Comment: or you can drive a transformer with it - solid state tesla coil - http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1256402716

Comment: Yeah, or really anything that needs a varying voltage of some sort, motors and the like.

Answer (score 6):

The primary use for PWM is controlling a motor. You (normally) do it to control the speed at which the motor runs. There are two contributing factors to help this work. First of all, a motor has a fair amount of physical inertia, so it doesn't slow down or speed up terribly quickly as you turn the voltage on and off. Second, the magnetic field that's generated when the voltage runs through the coils also has a degree of "inertia" -- i.e., it takes a bit for the field to collapse when you turn the current off, and a while for it to build back up when you turn the current on.

Together those mean you can vary the speed of the motor over a fairly wide range, and it'll still run reasonably smoothly rather than doing much speeding up/slowing down as you change the duty cycle of the PWM signal.

Note, however, that in most cases you *do* need a separate driver chip to run any more than a truly minuscule motor -- though PWM allows you to generate the right type of signal to control a motor nicely, a typical microcontroller is not built to source or sink the kind of current to run a motor.

Answer (score 4):

Some devices such as motors and LEDs operate more efficiently (or at all) with a specific input voltage, so when you want say a variable speed or brightness, varying the analogue voltage is generally an unsatisfactory solution and is also more complex to achieve using a digital device.  In these cases PWM is typically used.

If you do want an analogue voltage from a PWM then you can apply a low pass filter on the output, but this will not produce the linear response of a true DAC output.

Answer (score 3):

Be it for motor control, tuning the brightness of an led, etc, essentially it is used as a 1 bit DAC.  If you have something that ideally wants a DC voltage but something in the system doesnt react very fast (like your eyes watching an led, or the rotor on a motor) if you feed it a waveform (often sine or pwm) you will basically get the integral.  A pwm is not as fancy as a real one bit dac like you would see in a stereo system (one bit dac was an advertised feature for cd players back in the day), you are not using it to make an output change on a per cycle basis, but over many pwm cycles.  If you think about a square wave being a 50% duty cycle half high, half low, take an average or integral of it and you can sorta visualize that half the time it is above the midway point between the high and low voltages.  If you had a pwm output where it was high 3/4ths of the cycle then low 1/4th of the cycle that average is now 3/4ths the difference between the low voltage and the high.  If you fed a DC motor or led or something like that you would get what appears to be 3/4ths of the output of what you would have if you had the output set at the high voltage.  A 25% high, 75% low would give you 25% of that always on voltage and so on.

So yes, PWM is mostly used like a DAC but as a DAC in the sense that it is used to drive motors and backlights and leds and other things that may want to be voltage controlled and somewhere in the system, be it a capacitor that integrates, a motor with physical response time limitations or the human eye that cannot see the led blinking.  so mostly used as a DAC and mostly used for motor control are both correct statements.

You find them on microcontrollers for that reason, think about the places where you use microcontrollers and you find places where you also want to control something with pwm.

Answer (score 2):

One common usage is servo motor control. The width of the PWM signal will control the degree of the servo output.

Answer (score 1):

Pulse Width Modulation, it is used quite a lot in motor speed control. Anything that requires a voltage that's not the high or low voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Among all the good anwers, another novelty usage of PWM is simple, and perhaps low fi, sound generation. The simplest method is to convert the amplitude of the raw sound signal's amplitude and map that against the duty cycle of the PWM output.

This page is a good example, but it is for the Atmel AVR micros rather than the PIC micros.
http://aquaticus.info/pwm-music

Answer (score 1):

You can use programmable PWM to create square-waves.

On a bigger microcontroller (LM3s9l97 et al.) you can to really complex waveforms.

Basically you can get four to six events for every cycle of the counter (zero, A, B, load and two more for A and B in up-down-mode) and you can decide what to do on each event: toggle the ouput, set the output to low and set the output to high.

You can do really nifty stuff with that.